# Linux/shell command to control screen brightness in android

Tags: android, linux, shell, linux-kernel, sh

I am working on a kiosk project using an android tablet.If there is no input power to the kiosk for a long time then, the tablet will eventually shutdown.In order to auto-reboot the tab when the power comes back I modified the code in my tabs battery animation file(ipod) using:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sleep 300
/system/bin/reboot
```

However,during the sleep period(shown above),the tabs screen remains in the ON state (and hence takes longer retries for the tab to charge and bootup).I need to turn the screen OFF.
What is the command I should use prior to the sleep command to turn my tabs screen OFF during the charging/bootup stage. Thanks !

Comment: Try [this](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/blog/set-android-brightness-adb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command too,

```
echo 100 > /sys/devices/platform/nov_cabc.0/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
```

or

```
echo 100 > brightness
```

Comment: Should I use this 'cat 100 > /sys/devices/platform/nov_cabc.0/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' right before my sleep command in my ipod file ? And,I hope I dont have to send that command through adb ,right?

Comment: For my tab,I found that the brightness file is located at '/sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' . Using adb,going to shell and the folder, I tried 'echo 1 > brightness' and it worked. However using say cat 255 > brightness shows 'cat :can't open '255':No such file or directory'.

Comment: Updated according to your experience, now try it to full brightness.

Comment: I used 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' before the sleep in my file.As expected, the brightness of the screen was low.Now,I wanted to make the screen go completely off ,for which I used 'echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' , however I observed that the screen brightness didnt go off at all,instead some default brightness was been taken.How can I make the screen go completely off?

Comment: See this is only for changing brightness but not for power off the screen.

Comment: Agree, but when I executed the echo 0 command using adb I was completely able to turn off the screen.Using echo 1/echo 255(in the file) is changing brightness properly but not echo 0. Is there any other value to be given for turning off the screen ?

Comment: Used just 'input keyevent 26' before the sleep command,but in vain :(

Comment: Use it like this `adb shell input keyevent 26`

Comment: This is the code in my file now :#!/system/bin/sh
adb shell input keyevent 26
sleep 60
/system/bin/reboot  .... but screen not turning off.

Comment: Ok, please ask that question individually other than here, cause I don't have any other solution for power off.

Comment: OK,thanks for your patience.You certainly did show me a path,I will work on it.Thank you :)

Comment: :Above the sleep command I gave 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness'   and   'echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' , one after the other in pairs for about 7-8 times and observed that I was able to turn off the screen completely.Weird, but true !

Comment: Basher, How is it that keyevent 26 turns off screen, but echo o > brightness, doesn't ? Did you resolve this issue ?